# Difference 記念日 vs 周年

Tags: meaning, nuances

What exactly is the difference betweekn 記念日 and 周年? I found both to mean "anniversary".
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

周年 just indicates the number of **years** that something has been in continuing or in operation. This term is used in regards to anniversaries, but only as a description of what the anniversary is for.

記念 is remembrance or commemoration. Adding 日 to it makes it 'Commemoration **Day**', or 'Anniversary'.

These two terms are often used together to indicate both the celebration/commemoration and what specifically it is celebrating.

> 10**周年**(の)結婚**記念日**. Day of celebration of 10 years of marriage; 10-year (marriage) anniversary.